# Where can I find scripts/screenplays/transcripts of movies and TV shows?

Tags: faq

As a general case, Where can I find scripts/screenplays/transcripts of movies and TV shows?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a number of websites that provide access to movie and TV scripts. I'm unsure of the legality of any of them. But here are a few of the popular ones:

- [IMSDb](http://www.imsdb.com/): The Internet Movie Script Database
- [Script-O-Rama](http://www.script-o-rama.com/)
- [SimplyScripts](http://www.simplyscripts.com/)
- [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/gds/Movie-Scripts-Buying-Guide-/10000000177627449/g.html): Movie script buying guide

Answer (score 3):

There's also...

- [Springfield! Springfield! Movie and TV show scripts](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk)
- [Movie Transcript Database for iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch](https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=835224173&mt=8)
- Movie Transcript Database is also available for Android

Answer (score 3):

Best articles ever, and scripts photocopied from the originals...

http://www.cinephiliabeyond.org/

Answer (score 1):

One website that's missing from all the above answers is:

- https://www.scriptslug.com

Answer (score -1):

Springfield springfield was my site of choice until it was no more ...

Found:
https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/ ... might want to give it a shot.