# Are the scripts published online official?

Tags: screenplay

From time to time I've seen movies' or TV show episodes' scripts posted or quoted online - at first they were The Simpsons episodes, but Star Wars and Harry Potter films too, for example. There's even [a question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15160/19268) about sites in which to find scripts.

**Are those scripts *official*?**

I don't know if they are published by the directors/writers/producers, or if they are fan made. They seem *too detailed* to be fan made - and considered too much *canon* for just being the opinion of lots of nerds -, but I can't imagine **why** nor **where** do they publish them. What's the intention in publishing them?

Comment: I count 8 questions in the body alone.  If someone knows the answer to one, should they reply?  I doubt I'd bother..

Comment: Please simplify your question to one question only, and not several.

Comment: It's not that the OP has multiple questions, it's just a broad topic and a lot of guessing is occurring in the main question. I think the only real question is the subject.

Comment: I don't really see how to make my point being more precise. I'm curious about the scripts I've seen online and want to understand what's about them. You could think of the subject as _the one_ question, but I don't think it reflects my hole doubt.

Comment: How about something like "How and why are some scripts made public while others are not?" and post some links to the scripts you mention that you've found and clarify your question with statements rather than more questions.... Granted, that's a pretty broad question and may get closed as being broad... but it's still a better phrasing.

Comment: What do you mean by 'public'? Publicly available? (I think you already know the question to that). Public domain? (In most cases, no.)

Comment: There are shooting scripts and draft scripts, which are what they sound like, and are official scripts. Then there's transcripts, which are more or less "fanmade", they are generated by either watching somethings and writing down dialogue (and sometimes scene descriptions, but many transcripts lack that altogether) or by getting the subtitle files and going from that. Hence the "trans" part of the scripts.

Answer (score 1):

[As stated in the question you link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15160/5603), the legality of these scripts is unconfirmed. Obviously, as with anything posted on the internet, unless you can verify the source yourself there's no guarantee that anything is as presented.

Using [Internet Movie Script Database](http://www.imsdb.com/) as an example, many of these scripts do not even list who posted them to the site and the site itself [disclaims](http://www.imsdb.com/disclaimer/) according to Fair Use.

Answer (score 1):

There are shooting scripts and draft scripts, which are what they sound like, and are official scripts.

Then there's transcripts, which are more or less "fanmade", they are generated by either watching something and writing down dialogue (and sometimes scene descriptions, but many transcripts lack that altogether) or by getting the subtitle files and going from that. Hence the "trans" part of the scripts.