# List of languages spoken in "Vikings" TV series

Tags: dialogue, vikings, subtitles

In 3 seasons of *Vikings* we have heard characters spoken in Old Norse, Old English and Old French, and Latin, beside few shouts in Latvian in the first episode.

Have there been more languages that I might have missed?

And most important, Where could I find transcripts or subtitles for those dialogues in their respective languages?

Apologies again if asking for links to other sites is not allowed, I just acted out of confidence that if noone pointed out to that in this topic: [Where can I find scripts/screenplays/transcripts of movies and TV shows?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15160/where-can-i-find-scripts-screenplays-transcripts-of-movies-and-tv-shows), then perhaps it is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, There are four major "dead" languages that are spoken in the show which are Latin, Old Norse, Anglo-Saxon and old French. Quoting [Michael Hirst](http://www.medievalists.net/2015/02/qa-michael-hirst-creator-writer-vikings/):

> And here’s a very important thing: if you include Latin as a dead language, we have FOUR dead languages in the show. We have people speaking Anglo-Saxon, Old Norse, Old French (when they raid Paris, which sounds more like German than French, actually) and Latin, and can you tell me ANY other network show that has people speaking four dead languages in it?

The French however changed eventually to standard modern French as the show progressed. And also there's some Latvian as you suggest in the first episode of the first season.

Other than that I have noted:

1. Arabic spoken by Emir Ziyadat-Allah in Kairouan and by the Andalusians.
2. Greek spoken by Commander Euphemios and Kasia.
3. Hindi/Urdu spoken in the markets of Kattegat.